# Turkish characters could not be displayed in website. Tomcat Server, Mysql Database

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, encoding, tomcat7

Turkish characters displayed as '?' and inserted the database incorrectly.
I can change the text in phpmyadmin and make it turkish again. By this way everything works perfect.

My encoding filter:

```
private String encoding;

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");

    if (encoding == null)
        encoding = "UTF-8";
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Respect the client-specified character encoding
    // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
    if (null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
        request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);

    /**
     * Set the default response content type and encoding
     */
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    next.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void destroy() {
}
```

I don't have turkish character problem in localhost.I see the problem in www.gurkanilleez.com only.

Comment: I solved the problem
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=UTF-8
just append 'characterEncoding=UTF-8'

Answer (score 0):

Question marks for each non-English character?  What probably happened:

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

Use utf8 instead of latin1.

For JDBC, include `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the getConnection() call.

There are several threads about Turkish character set problems in stackoverflow; read them.

Comment: I am using Hibernate. I tried your solutions but no effect at all

Answer (score 0):

I cannot make a comment because of my reputation. I visited your website and I see the turkish characters as they should be. So, there is no problem or?

Comment: there is a problem when input field is sent to the database.